# Video live streaming with Cordova and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova

I want to create an app with Cordova where users will be able to stream video (with audio) from their camera and other users can watch live. On the server's side with NodeJS this is an easy task. I was wondering if there is an API (plugin or something) in Cordova that would work similarly to Node.

Ideally it would work like this:

```
var http = require('http'); // Like Node's http
var camera = require('camera'); // Imaginary API

camera.record(function(err, stream){ // Stream like Node's readable streams

    var req = http.request({
        hostname: 'my.server',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'x-streaming-headsup': '1' }
    }, function(res){

    });    

    stream.pipe(req);

});
```

Or if recorded video is being buffered into a file, maybe stream from that file with a similar method?

Thanks

Comment: You might look into the [Opentok Cordova plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.tokbox.cordova.opentok) from the Cordova Plugin Registry.

Comment: @filoxo as I understand this a paid service. I would like to stream the video to my own server in a method similar to my example.